# "hour" int taken from NSDate not behaving as expected at midnight?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, integer

I feel like I've lost my mind. Can someone tell me what's going on here? Also, I'm sure there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do, but I'm not interested in that now. I'd just like to solve the mystery of why my ints are not responding to logic as expected.

```
// Set "At: " field close to current time
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
int hour = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm"];
int minute = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];
NSLog(@"currently %i:%i",hour, minute);

if(hour >= 12){ // convert to AM/PM
    selectedMeridiem = 1;
    if(hour != 12){
        hour = hour - 12;
    }
}
else{
    selectedMeridiem = 0;
    if(hour == 0){
        hour = 12;
    }
}

NSLog(@"test");

selectedHour = hour - 1;

if(selectedHour <= 0){
    selectedHour = 11;
}
```

When I debug the above code with my clock set to 12:XX AM, the integer "hour" returned is 0. But then any if statements with the condition if(hour == 0) are not evaluated. Likewise, this would not be evaluated either: if(hour < 1). The code above puts the hour int into another int, selectedHour (don't worry about why I'm doing this for now), but selectedHour suffers from the same weird behavior; the if(selectedHour <= 0) line is never evaluated. Am I going crazy, or am I just an idiot? Maybe there's some behavior of 0 integers that I'm not aware of. All of my code runs fine as long as it's not 12:XX AM.

Comment: What type is selectedHour? If it is unsigned you are gonna have a problem here when hour is < 1.

Comment: I cannot duplicate the behavior. Could it be that your tests were flawed and you accidentally made the classic mistake of `if (hour = 0)`?

Comment: I'm having the same problem when taking the floatValue from [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]

Comment: Chuck, thanks for checking but no, the single = isn't the problem (thought I'm not saying I've never made that mistake!) Knowing that you can't duplicate it helps...

Comment: Well, now XCode is skipping right over an NSLog(@"test"); ... I guess maybe it's a problem with my installation. I just reformatted yesterday. Going to try reinstalling XCode.

Comment: I don't see any line that even says NSLog(@"Test"). Can you post your actual code?

Comment: Also, instead of spending so much time on this, you should just do it the correct way ;)

Comment: Just edited to show where I put the NSLog(@"test") which wasn't even outputting. Xcode was acting weird in debugging (skipping to weird lines) and lines of code that I had commented out were continuing to be run, so I'm just reinstalling it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my Xcode installation oddly enough. Just reinstalled everything and it's working correctly now. Weird because it was just causing comparisons to integers of value "0" to be off.